# What is the kernmagic extension?

Tags: python, ipython, enthought, conda

When installing EPD's Python distribution, the installer creates an IPython profile with the following entry in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`:

```
# c.TerminalIPythonApp.extensions = ['kernmagic']
```

As discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574587/how-do-i-upgrade-kernmagic-to-fix-this-ipython-error), this can [cause errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574587/how-do-i-upgrade-kernmagic-to-fix-this-ipython-error) if someone later wants to use a different IPython distribution (e.g. `conda`), since this extension isn't installed by default.

With this, my question is **what exactly** is `kernmagic`? I read that it adds some additional `magics` to IPython, but what are they?

Less importantly, assuming that I don't use EPD but I want to use this extension, besides the manual installation through `hg clone` and `python setup.py build`, how can I install it using `pip`?

Answer (score 4):

[It's a collection of %magics that I wrote for myself](https://bitbucket.org/robertkern/kernmagic). The documentation for all of the magics that are added [can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/robertkern/kernmagic/src/4518888c6d230b1a0a60a4393ba286672b5070e5/help.txt?at=default). Though I was not the individual who added by default to older versions of EPD, I apologize for the confusion. Yes, it is currently only available via the checkout; I have not made an official release of it.